# When using a specific button on discord my bot crashes

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When I use a specific button on discord it crashes the bot and gives this error:

```
E:\TicketBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at RequestHandler.execute (E:\TicketBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (E:\TicketBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async ButtonInteraction.reply (E:\TicketBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:99:5)
    at async Object.execute (E:\TicketBot\events\interactionCreate2.js:82:21) {
```

This is the code for the embed and button that I use when it crashes

```js
const embed = new client.discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('FF0000')
    .setAuthor({name: `${interaction.user.username}'s Ticket`, iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/764964854087417899/941868628138135622/Hecker.png'})
    .setDescription('Test')
    .setTimestamp();

const row = new client.discord.MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new client.discord.MessageButton()
    .setCustomId('close-ticket')
    .setLabel('Close')
    .setEmoji('')
    .setStyle('DANGER'),
);
```

Comment: Hello, could you please show us your code that you think causes the problem?

Comment: I assume this means that you are replying to an interaction twice

Answer (score 0):

Using the same interaction twice causes this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it could help future readers with the same question.